# How do you loop through a db2 resultset using a shell script to process each record returned by the query?

Tags: sql, shell, unix, db2

I have a db2 database and I want to do the following via a shell script in unix:

(1) run a query

```
SELECT MEMBERID FROM MEMBERS WHERE AGE<16
```

(2) then for each record returned by this query, I want to update it in this way:

```
UPDATE MEMBERS SET ADULT='N' WHERE MEMBERID=<the member id returned above>
```

I already know how to connect to db2 and run the SELECT and get the value of MEMBERID for processing. However, I can't figure out how loop through a resultset of multiple records returned by the query. Can anyone help me how to go about doing that?
How does one loop through a db2 resultset in unix so that this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use db2, but in Oracle it would be

```
UPDATE MEMBERS 
   SET ADULT='N' 
 WHERE MEMBERID IN (SELECT MEMBERID 
                      FROM MEMBERS
                     WHERE AGE<16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to loop the the results set?

Simply:

```
UPDATE members
SET adult = 'N'
WHERE age < 16
```

SQL is a set based language...looping through a results set and running more SQL for each row should be avoided if at all possible.  It's a common mistake for people used to writing in procedural languages.  There's an acronym to remember when it comes to SQL, RBAR: Row-By-Agonizing-Row

Google *SQL RBAR* for more information...and be sure to look at the example here
[RBAR vs. Set based programming for SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687512/rbar-vs-set-based-programming-for-sql)