# Run a Select-into command to create a new table for each UNIQUE value of a particular column

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, sql-server-2008-r2, create-table, select-into

I have a table on SQL Server database from which I need to create different tables for  each unique value of a particular column.

I tried below code:

```
DECLARE @i int 
DECLARE @numrows int
DECLARE @indexcount int
DECLARE @Group varchar
DECLARE @temp_table TABLE (
    idx smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1), Group varchar(200)
    )

-- populate group table
INSERT @temp_table
SELECT distinct Column_3 FROM Existing_Table

-- enumerate the table
SET @i = 1
SET @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp_table)
SET @indexcount = (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @temp_table) 
IF @numrows > 0
    WHILE (@i <= @indexcount)
    BEGIN
      -- get the next Group primary key
        SET @Group = (SELECT Group FROM @temp_table WHERE idx = @i);
        IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.New_Table_@Group', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
            DROP TABLE dbo.New_Table_@Group;
        select Column_1, Column_2  
        into New_Table_@Group
        from Existing_Table where Column_3 = @Group;
        -- increment counter for next employee
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
```

This is executing and without prompting any error, but is also failing to give the expected result. It does not create any new table. While executing it shows that so-and-so number of rows affected but when I check the list of tables, no such new table will be created.

Can someone please help achieve the expected result? Any help is much appreciated.

[depiction of existing table and new tables to be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkhIZ.jpg) - Here is a depiction of the table that I have and the intended resultant table to be achieved.

Comment: Your code snippet will create a single new table named `dbo.New_Table_@Group` but drop and recreate it each iteration. You need to use dynamic SQL for your task. See http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html.

Comment: @DanGuzman I looked into the link that you suggested but I couldn't make out much as this is very much new to me. I got to know about when to not use the way that I have used variables but couldn't find(or I did not understand) about how to use it in a scenario similar to that of mine.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL syntax does not allow one to parameterize object names so you need to use dynamic SQL for this task.

Below is a script that shows how to build and execute a dynamic script to (re)create a table for each group. I used a cursor instead of a pseudo cursor (loop) and table variable in this example since the loop provides no value over a cursor in this case; both are [RBAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687512/rbar-vs-set-based-programming-for-sql) methods.

Note that this dynamic SQL method is not something to be done routinely as it may be an indicator of a flawed application design. Here, it seems there should be a single table for all groups rather separate tables because they appear the be the same entity. See Erland Sommarskog's [the Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for a thorough discussion on the subject.

```
DECLARE @Group varchar(200);
DECLARE @CreateTableScript nvarchar(MAX);

DECLARE groups CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT
          Column_3 AS [Group]
        , N'IF OBJECT_ID(N''dbo.' + QUOTENAME('New_Table_' + Column_3) + ''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL 
                DROP TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME('New_Table_' + Column_3) + ';
            select Column_1, Column_2  
            into dbo.' + QUOTENAME('New_Table_' + Column_3) + '
            from Existing_Table where Column_3 = @Group;' AS CreateTableScript
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Column_3 FROM Existing_Table) AS groups;

OPEN groups;
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM groups INTO @Group, @CreateTableScript;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;
    PRINT @CreateTableScript;
    EXEC sp_executesql
          @CreateTableScript
        , N'@Group varchar(200)'
        , @Group = @Group;
END;
CLOSE groups;
DEALLOCATE groups;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Dan! Now this works exactly the way I wanted it to. Thanks again.

Comment: Dan, lately I observed that this is not creating tables for all the values in one go. I have placed this inside a stored procedure and calling this stored procedure from an application on page load. So it seems I will have to load the page 2-3 time to have the tables created. even after that, some times, I notice that tables 1 or 2 values still be missed or  be created with no values. Why would this be happening? How to fix this?

Comment: @Shreesha, I tested the T-SQL code and it works as expected from SSMS. Remove the `PRINT` statement (which is only for debugging) and add `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedure if you haven't already done so. That will avoid the DONE_IN_PROC (rowcount) messages from confusing applications that don't process all the result sets returned and prevent the proc from running to completion.