# CHARINDEX does not return the correct index into the search string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in a single element in a database table:

```
Port Jefferson Station, NY 11776-2598   
Northport, NY 11768                     
Garden City, NY 11530
```

I am trying to break each line up into a new table which contains a city field, a state field and a zip code field.

I am running a script with the following code to pick up the City value:

```
Create function [dbo].[fnBuildCityState](@AddressCity varchar(40))
RETURNS @NameTable TABLE
(
    City VARCHAR(255),
    State VARCHAR(255),
    Zip VARCHAR(255)
) 
as
BEGIN

-- Index and word variables.
DECLARE @AccountNameEndIndex INT;
DECLARE @FirstWordEndIndex   INT;
DECLARE @SecondWordEndIndex  INT;
DECLARE @ThirdWordEndIndex   INT;
DECLARE @FirstWord       NVARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @SecondWord      NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @ThirdWord       NVARCHAR(50);

SET @AddressCity = RTRIM(ISNULL(@AddressCity,'No Address, City ZipCode'))
if (LEN(@AddressCity)<3)
BEGIN
    SET @AddressCity = 'No Address, City ZipCode'
END

-- Get the last index.
SET @AccountNameEndIndex = LEN(@AddressCity) - 1;
-- Get the first word.
SET @FirstWordEndIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @AddressCity, 0);
SET @FirstWord         = SUBSTRING(@AddressCity, 0, @FirstWordEndIndex);



INSERT INTO @NameTable (City, State, Zip)
VALUES (@FirstWord, @SecondWord, @ThirdWord)

RETURN
END
```

When I run the code, and look at the resulting table, I see this output:

```
City                     State                Zip
Port Jef                 NULL                 NULL
Northpor                 NULL                 NULL
Garden C                 NULL                 NULL
```

The line of code which should return the index to the location of the comma in the input is

> SET @FirstWordEndIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @AddressCity, 0);

It appears to always return a value of 8 regardless of where the comma is in the string.

Any idea why?

Comment: you declared the variable as size 8 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific answer to your question is because you defined `@FirstWord` as `NVARCHAR(8)` so its only going to contain up to 8 chars.

But the bigger question is why are you trying trying to do that [RBAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687512/rbar-vs-set-based-programming-for-sql)? SQL is set-based for a reason... you can build a query to do everything you need in one hit e.g.

```
SELECT b.City, C.[State], c.ZipCode
FROM (
    VALUES
    ('Port Jefferson Station, NY 11776-2598'),
    ('Northport, NY 11768'),
    ('Garden City, NY 11530')
) x ([Address])
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
    (CHARINDEX(',', x.[Address], 0))
) a (FirstComma)
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
    (SUBSTRING(x.[Address],1,a.FirstComma-1)
    , SUBSTRING(x.[Address],a.FirstComma+2,LEN(x.[Address])))
) b (City,SecondString)
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
    (SUBSTRING(b.SecondString,1,2)
    , SUBSTRING(b.SecondString,4,LEN(b.SecondString)))
) c ([State],ZipCode);
```

Returns:

| City | State | ZipCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Port Jefferson Station | NY | 11776-2598 |
| Northport | NY | 11768 |
| Garden City | NY | 11530 |

This is simplistic and doesn't cover your edge cases such as no address, or a state with a length other then 2 characters. But thats all stuff you can easily sort out.

The point of using using `CROSS APPLY` is to avoid having to repeat the same calculations in multiple places - which a query without `CROSS APPLY` would need to do.

Comment: I appreciate your question/explanation.  This is just a small part of a larger script which will be coming in from an outside vendor and needs messaging before inserting into our tables.  As for your first point, the limit of 8 characters was the bug as the code was copied from a different source and I failed to change that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is based on *tokenization* instead of string parsing.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Port Jefferson Station, NY 11776-2598'),
('Northport, NY 11768'),   
('Garden City, NY 11530');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT t.*
    , city = c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , state = LEFT(TRIM(c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')), 2)
    , zip = SUBSTRING(TRIM(c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')), 3, 50)
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | city | state | zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Port Jefferson Station, NY 11776-2598 | Port Jefferson Station | NY | 11776-2598 |
| 2 | Northport, NY 11768 | Northport | NY | 11768 |
| 3 | Garden City, NY 11530 | Garden City | NY | 11530 |

Answer (score 0):

I tend to lean towards JSON when parsing strings

**Example**

```
Select City  = JSON_VALUE(JS1,'$[0]')
      ,State = JSON_VALUE(JS2,'$[0]')
      ,ZIP   = JSON_VALUE(JS2,'$[1]')
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(Address,',','","')+'"]') ) B(JS1)
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(ltrim(JSON_VALUE(JS1,'$[1]')),' ','","')+'"]') ) C(JS2)
```

**Results**

```
City                    State   ZIP
Port Jefferson Station  NY      11776-2598
Northport               NY      11768
Garden City             NY      11530
```

If you wanted to use as a TVF

```
Declare @AddressCity varchar(max) = 'Port Jefferson Station, NY 11776-2598'

Select City  = JSON_VALUE(JS1,'$[0]')
      ,State = JSON_VALUE(JS2,'$[0]')
      ,ZIP   = JSON_VALUE(JS2,'$[1]')
 From (values ('["'+replace(@AddressCity,',','","')+'"]') ) A(JS1)
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(ltrim(JSON_VALUE(JS1,'$[1]')),' ','","')+'"]') ) B(JS2)
```